# Why my SharePoint web ContentTypes collection is empty?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, content-type

I have default sharepoint web site.
In events reciever of Pages library i can access my current web:

**var web=properties.Web;**

And i got very strange problem. **web.ContentTypes** collection is emtpy. I cannot get and access any content type there! When via website i see all content types for current web.

Why this ContentTypes collection is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try web.AvailableContentTypes.

It contains all content types that can be used on the site, rather than just the ones defined on this particular site.

See:

[SPWeb.ContentTypes on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.contenttypes.aspx)